# Query a database without any migrations Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I simply want to query a database in Django. I don't want any migrations created as it is a read-only database. I have been unable to get it to work because of this.

I simply want to perform an SQL query on a database and use the data, no model needed. Is this possible within Django or should I just opt for using normal python methods for this?

Just using `cursor.execute()` and being able to create a `connection` would be perfect, but Django seems persistent to create a migration if I add the database in the settings.

Comment: The question is: How to use Django, but only views and templates without models? that breaks the pattern.

Comment: @Gocht I just want to quick grab some data from a database to display. Nothing is saved. There really is no need for any kind of model. Just essentially want to execute and SQL query and get the data.

Comment: In other words, you don't want to use the entire ORM - not sure it's a good idea, but it should be possible. In an attempt to disable migrations, does [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NotSqrt/5f3c76cd15e40ef62d09) help?

Comment: @jweyrich correct. I have no need for any kind of object. This whole project is essentially a read-only kind of application so it seems using Django wasn't really needed, but alas here I am.

Comment: @jweyrich I'll give that gist a try

Comment: @jweyrich still getting the Django error about being unable to create migrations: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1142, "CREATE command denied to user 'user@example.com' for table 'django_migrations'")`

Comment: If you don't want to use the django ORM then it would be easier and simpler to just use the appropriate python database library and connect to the DB directly.

Comment: @dgel that is what I was thinking would be best.

Comment: @Fogest: Django 1.8? Did you put that code in your settings module?

Comment: @jweyrich yes, and yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Just use the appropriate python database library to connect to the DB directly and perform your query.

## Long answer

If you absolutely need to use django's DB connection but don't want to deal with any migrations:

1. Turn off all apps that have any models by removing them from `INSTALLED_APPS`. This would include:

   - `django.contrib.admin`
   - `django.contrib.auth`
   - `django.contrib.contenttypes`
   - `django.contrib.sessions`

   You'll need to also disable their respective middleware classes.
2. Populate the correct [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases) settings then use [`connection.cursor()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to perform your query.
3. I believe you still may need to use [`DisableMigrations` hack](https://gist.github.com/NotSqrt/5f3c76cd15e40ef62d09) referenced by @jweyrich.